# Multiple "IF" statements in Excel but using the same phrase look up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can not figure out how to put 2 of the same `IF` statement but with a different result in case is not there then to do the second combination.

```
 =IF(C2737="XXX_SF",INDEX(TMParking_8_24!A:A,MATCH(Tracker!J2737&"xxxshortform",TMParking_8_24!F:F,0)),
```

The above formula is what I'm looking for. Incase `xxxshrotform` is not there I would like it to search for a `xx5shortform`. So I added the below to the second part of the formula:

```
INDEX(TMParking_8_24!A:A,MATCH(Tracker!J2737&"xx5shortform",TMParking_8_24!F:F,0)))
```

Within the `INDEX` the `xx5shortform` exists but it is not finding it.

Comment: Is there a space between the value in `Tracker!J2737` and `"xx5shortform"` that you are trying to lookup in `TMParking_8_24!F:F`?

Comment: I just checked and no there is not Brian.

Comment: Okay, because if you are searching for `example xx5shortform` in `TMParking_8_24!F:F` it won't find it because you are trying to find `examplexx5shortform`. Can you add a picture of the data?

Comment: Sure give me one second. Basically im trying to find "xxxshortform" and if that dose not exist then to look up "xx5shortform". But I will upload some pictures right now. Thank you Brian

Comment: https://s9.postimg.org/8zkm00ybz/pic1.jpg

Comment: https://s15.postimg.org/ui5zgro6j/pic2.jpg

Comment: Here are some pictures ^^^^

Comment: Is your data in Column F? It doesn't look like it. I would try the `IFERROR()` functions also as @Jeeped mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to pass control over to a second [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) if the first is not found.

```
=IF(C2737="XXX_SF",
     INDEX(TMParking_8_24!A:A,
          IFERROR(MATCH(Tracker!J2737&"xxxshortform",TMParking_8_24!F:F,0),
                  MATCH(Tracker!J2737&"xxshortform",TMParking_8_24!F:F,0))), "")
```

There was no indication as to what to return if C2737 does not equal XXX_SF nor what to do if the second match does not work.

Comment: btw, I've corrected `xxxshrotform` to `xxxshortform`.

Comment: I didn't think of including the `IFERROR()` function. Makes sense. Very insightful!

Comment: What if `C2737="XXX_SF"` and the second `MATCH()`, which I think should be `xx5shortform`, isn't found?

Comment: You're correct about `xx5shortform` of course but I'll leave that to the OP to correct. There was no indication given as to what to return with no match on the second try (noted within my response).

Comment: Check out my 2 pictures I provided above. It will explain a lot more in detail I think.

Comment: uh... yeah. I don't do pictures so much.